# Why are most scenes in a car recorded with chroma?

Tags: film-techniques

I'm aware of "[How do they film scenes with the actors driving in a car?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/how-do-they-film-scenes-with-the-actors-driving-in-a-car)" in this site, but I'm more interested in the "why", not the "how".

Is it illegal to just drive a car recording/action without permissions in most jurisdictions? (this happens in many countries) Safety concerns? Or maybe it's just cheaper?

Comment: Safety comes to mind as one obvious reason. I'm sure that even if it were legal, a big camera rig would be a bit hard to see around, and also, it's simply safer to drive without distractions... (like not messing up your lines)

Comment: @David - A lot of times, cars with camera rigs on them (when actually shot on the road) are towed - the actor isn't really driving.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course this changes from country to country, but generally speaking it's not illegal to film on the streets, since it's a public area.

Most car scenes are recorded with chroma just for pratical reasons.

In a professional production you look for "quality" and you can achieve it only if you have **control**. It's all about control.

With a studio setting you get full control of the lights, the movements, etc. in one word, the scene. And of course, you minimize the hitches that can occurs in the real world (also safety concers).

However you should film outdoor shots to enrich and give credibility to your scene.

Comment: You've missed one key part of 'control' - it means you can use shots from different takes, without having to worry about 'background' elements being consistent (because a constant source is stitched in later).