# Are the driving scenes in the Office filmed while the actors are driving?

Tags: production, the-office

There is this question that has answers - [How do they film scenes with the actors driving in a car?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/how-do-they-film-scenes-with-the-actors-driving-in-a-car).

But it is really more about stunts and more aggressive driving.   My kids are watching The Office and they noticed that there is a lot of scenes that the people are driving in and it sure seems like they are driving.   Are they using the same methods as the above answer for "basic" driving scenes too or are some/all of the scenes filmed while they are driving?

Comment: Watch the blooper reels. You’ll see bloopers where Carrell takes a wrong turn, and and I believe there’s one where a driving stunt doesn’t time out right so they have to do it again. Also the scene where Michael is driving in his Sebring when he hits Meredith, pulls up in the PT Cruiser at the start of the MSPC.

Comment: They’re available on YouTube. Search “The Office bloopers”. I’ve found all but Season 1 on there

Comment: @Tetsujin - this is the US version.   If I thought that they used a pull car or whatever I wouldn't have asked.   Some of the car scenes show outside the car views.   I can't really think of another show that has such an influx of car scenes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of [the driving scenes in The Office are real](http://theofficebloopers.com/trivia/are-the-office-driving-scenes-real/). There's a blooper that shows Steve Carell taking a wrong turn. The article linked also references some discussions in Angela Kinsey and Jenna Fisher's [Office Ladies Podcast](https://officeladies.com/). Pretty interesting!

Comment: Not *all* scenes are real. The scenes in the moving van with Darryl, Michael and Holly (when Holly moves out of state) are on a flatbed truck, as evidenced by the blooper reel which includes a blooper where the car seems to drive off at the completely wrong time in the scene, without Darryl controlling the vehicle. It's a mix of both real and fake driving.